# Is there exist a function in Sage that applies a permutation to a list?

Tags: python, permutation, sage

I have the following problem in Sage:

I have a collection of permutation objects and a collection of lists, each of length 2. I was hoping there was a built-in function to apply a permutation to a list in the following way, e.g.:

```
result = (1,2,4)(3,5).apply_to([1,3])
print result
[2,5]
```

If not, any tips on how to write this function are appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: btw: while people here are sure qualified and willing to help with sage, note that there is also https://ask.sagemath.org ... just in case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to the answer from hiro protagonist, but perhaps more direct:

```
sage: a = Permutation('(1,2,4)(3,5)')
sage: result = [a(i) for i in [1,3]]
sage: result
[2, 5]
```

One point is that permutations in Sage can be called as functions, which is why the second line works.

Comment: @hiroprotagonist Thank you to the both of you for your help! I implemented it and it works quite well.

Comment: @hiroprotagonist: I discovered this by creating the permutation `a` and looking at its docstring via `a?`.

Answer (score 1):

you could try this using [`from_cycles`](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/combinat/sage/combinat/permutation.html#sage.combinat.permutation.from_cycles):

```
sage: from sage.combinat import permutation
sage: perm = permutation.from_cycles(5, ((1,2,4), (3,5)))
sage: perm  # -> [2, 4, 5, 1, 3]
sage: res = [perm[i-1] for i in [1, 3]]
sage: res   # -> [2, 5]
```

the `-1` in `perm[i-1]` is needed because your permutation starts at `1` and not at `0`. there is a more elegant way to apply a permutation to a list: see [John Palmieri's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44502313/4954037).